# incorrect order of files in dragdrop event in vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net

I'm dragging multiple files from Windows Explorer into my VB.net program.
Everything works, except that in the DragDrop event the order of files that I get from e.Data.GetData, appears to be random. At least it's not in the same order as the files are listed in Windows Explorer.

Here's the code in DragDrop

```
Dim Files() As String
Files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
```

So as an example in Windows Explorer I have 4 files: 001.txt, 002.txt, 003.txt and 004.txt. They are listed in that order. But the order in the Files() array is 002.txt, 003.txt, 004.txt, 001.txt

Does anyone know how the order is determined, and whether that can be modified somehow?

Comment: Explorer presents files as a "view": you can sort by name, date, size, etc.  But the order they are returned in DragDrap is probably dependent on something else like creation date.  Someone else might want them in the order they are Ctl-Click added to the files selection in Explorer.  Thats not going to happen either.  You arent going to know what order they were selected nor how Explorer has them sorted, so just sort them yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix - I'd be quite happy to sort by creation date, but I don't know how to do that - e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)  gives you a string array, but I've not seen a way to get any other information about the  dragged files. In the example I gave obviously you could order by the file name, but that was just an artificial example, that won't work for me.

Comment: I think what I'll do is, for each file just use the filename returned from e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) to look up the file information I was hoping there'd be a way to do it without resorting to this, but at least this will work.